# Как можно улучшить функцию?

Tags: python

народ, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать функцию подешевле в плане потребления проца на функцию. Вывод функции должен быть такой же. Вот пример:

```
def FindPixel(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """Функция вернёт цвет пикселей картинки"""
    our_base_screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2,))
    pixel_values = list(our_base_screen.getdata())
    return (pixel_values)
​
#  Пример вывода [(127, 135, 145), (127, 135, 145), (127, 135, 145)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Не имею понятия, с какой библиотекой вы работаете, но для поставленной задачи ультрапупер как подходит **cv2 (*OpenCV*)**. Изображения в нем - numpy массивы. Формат считывания (`cv2.imread`) по умолчанию BGR (*не RGB, не запутайтесь. Это самое сложное для новичков в нем*). То есть для вашей задачи достаточно сделать срез массива (которым и является изображение) по шаблону `image[ y0:y1, x0:x1 ]`, где y0, y1 - индекс начала и конца строки, а x0, x1 - индекс начала и конца колонки. По опыту скажу, что работая с cv2, придет хорошее понимание numpy, а изучение его отдельно довольно таки неприятная задача.

Конвертация изображений не должна вызывать много сложностей. Повторюсь, что не знаю библиотеки, в которой вы работаете. Поищите сами.

### ps

По поводу «подешевле»: в numpy срез искомого вами массива сделан на си, что дает хорошую производительность.

### UPD: реализация для PIL изображений

```
FindPixel=lambda PIL_image, x0, y0, x1, y1: numpy.asarray(PIL_image)[ y0:y1, x0:x1 ]
```